# haskell stack to make executables for a project that do not use the library

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I have a haskell project that is mainly a library. To run some benchmarks I also have some small utilities for checking that some results are correct, also written in haskell. These utilities do not require the library to run and they are almost never built with debugging turned on. Here is an abbreviated version of package.yaml

```yaml
name: mypkg
version: 0.1.0.1

library:
  source-dirs: src
  exposed-modules:
    - Data.MyPkg
  dependencies:
    - base >= 4.7 && < 5
    - ghc >= 8.6.5

benchmarks:
  benchmark:
    main: Main.hs
    source-dirs: tools/Benchmark
    ghc-options: -DSOME_STUFF
    dependencies:
      - base >= 4.7 && < 5
      - ghc >= 8.6.5
      - mypkg

executables:
  checkresult:
    main: Main.hs
    source-dirs: tools/CheckResult
    dependencies:
      - base >= 4.7 && < 5
      - ghc >= 8.6.5
```

I run the benchmarks with a script that looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Building the benchmark"
if [[ "$1" = "verbose" ]]; then
  stack --work-dir .verbose-stack-dir/ build -j 4 --ghc-options -DMYPKG_VERBOSE mypkg:bench:benchmark;
else
  stack --work-dir .nonverbose-stack-dir/ build -j 4 mypkg:bench:benchmark
endif

echo "Checking results"
stack run mypkg:exe:checkresult
```

But when `stack run mypkg:exe:checkresult` runs the library is rebuilt even though `checkresult` does not depend on the library. Is there a way to disable that?

Comment: AFAIK this is not possible because Cabal generally assumes that any executable in a package depends on its library. I'd suggest that you extract `checkresult` into a separate package, i.e. turn your project into a multi-package project.